# How to remove multiple page links from Navigation menu on big cartel

Tags: bigcartel

I'm using the Luna Theme on Big Cartel. I am doing multiple blog posts using static pages. I saw on here that you could hide one link by using a code that I'll post at the bottom.
I'm trying to figure out how to hide multiple links on the footer.

```
{% for page in pages.all %}
<li>{{ page | link_to }}</li>
{% endfor %}

{% for page in pages.all %}
{% if page.name != 'PAGE NAME' %}<li>{{ page | link_to }}</li>{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `and` to include other pages to that `if` statement, like so:

```
{% for page in pages.all %}
  {% if page.name != 'Page One' and page.name != 'Page Two' and page.name != 'Page Three' %}<li>{{ page | link_to }}</li>{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Oh no! Nevermind.. it works bro!! Thank you so much.